# How to get handle for a specific application window in Python using pywin32?

Tags: python, pywin32, win32gui

I am attempting to modify some Python code that takes a screenshot of a particular application window in Windows 10. I am trying to use the `win32ui` / `win32gui` modules from the pywin32 package for this purpose. Here is the broken code:

```
def getWindow():
    name = "Windows PowerShell"
    window = win32ui.FindWindow(None, name)
    windowDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(window)
```

The last line causes the error. Here is the relevant portion of the console output:

```
  File ".\fake_file_name.py", line 9, in getWindow
    windowDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(window)
TypeError: The object is not a PyHANDLE object
```

I'm not very familiar with Python's type system or error messages, but this error makes it seem like `GetWindowDC` was expecting an argument with type `PyHANDLE`. [The documentation](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__FindWindow_meth.html) I could find for `win32gui.FindWindow` makes it seem like a `PyHANDLE` is indeed the output type.

On the other hand, these very similar lines of code came from a function that *does* work:

```
    hwin = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
    hwindc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwin)
```

Here is the [doc page](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__GetDesktopWindow_meth.html) for `win32gui.GetDesktopWindow`. If the previously shown error message didn't specifically mention `PyHANDLE`, I would just assume that `FindWindow` and `GetDesktopWindow` return different and incompatible types.

Can someone help me understand what this error message means and why it is appearing? I would also be interested in example code that gets a device context for a window with the name "Windows Powershell", as my broken code attempted to do.

Other info:
[Documentation page](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__GetWindowDC_meth.html) for `win32gui.GetWindowDC`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `EnumWindows()`,this will search all the window,Read it in [MSDN doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows):

```
import win32gui

def getShell():
    thelist = []
    def findit(hwnd,ctx):
        if win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd) == "Windows PowerShell": # check the title
            thelist.append(hwnd)

    win32gui.EnumWindows(findit,None)
    return thelist

b = getShell()
print(b) # b is the list of hwnd,contains those windows title is "Windows PowerShell"
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the output of your function to plug in with `win32gui.GetWindowDC` after some minor tweaks.