# how to handle "close/debug the program" window using os.system?

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.system

I've a python script that would run another exe file in a for loop

```
for i in files:
    os.system(f"My app.exe {i}")
```

at some point I get an error window "the app has started working" and presented with 2 options "close the program" or "debug the program" similar to the one in the image.

[image: simii]

Now, I wanted to put that inside a try and except. But the problem is that, it wouldn't go into exception because it's awaiting for me to click on either options so, is there a way around that?

Thank you

Comment: You basically can't interact or do anything (through your script) to a program run with `os.system`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using win32 to get a handle on the window and then do something with it [(see here for example).](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61151868/2264936)